# How to get json result value, returned by controller post action, after data was posted via form, generated by Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Well, I have ajax post form in my view with declared `OnComplete` javascript handler function name:

**Model**

```
class MyModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" id="inputToUpdate" />
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
                                                   {
                                                       HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                       OnComplete = "onComplete"
                                                   }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop2)
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(MyModel model)
{
     model = ChangeModel(model);
     return Json(model);
}
```

**Javascript OnComplete handler**

```
function onComplete() {
    var data = // get returned json data here
    $('#inputToUpdate').text(data.Prop1 + " " + data.Prop2);
}
```

**How can I, using such implementation, get returned json data in javascript onComplete method, to handle this data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do this?

```
function onComplete(data) {
    $('#inputToUpdate').text(data.Prop1 + " " + data.Prop2);
}
```

I think the JSON data will be passed as a parameter to the callback.

Comment: Thanks. The ajax data is, actually, stored in `data.responseText` so I had to use `var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);` but I got the point. Thanks, again, it worked.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry for not being accurate there dude, I couldn't recall the exact syntax required, but glad my answer was still helpful :)